# How to repeat a div N times in Angular

Tags: angular

```
<div ng-repeat="10">Text</div>
```

I don't have any object to use and I want it in Angular, not AngularJS or any other framework. Please make sure your solution support the  latest Angular.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

Typescript:

```
  fakeArray(length: number): Array<any> {
    if (length >= 0) {
      return new Array(length);
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of fakeArray(10);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div *ngFor="let item of itemList">{{item}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

in .ts file:->

```
nth_time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

in .html:->

```
<div *ngFor="let time of nth_time">{{time}}</div>
```

i hope this will help you.